# Start symbol START does not derive any sentence %start START

Tags: bison

This is my code for yacc:

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    extern File *yyin;
    extern int line;
%}
%token DATATYPE NUMBER ID RET MAIN KEYWORD AOP HEADER STB ENB
%start START 
%%
START:H MAIN STB S R ENB

      H:HEADER H|HEADER

      S:DS S
       |ES S
       |CS S
       |;
     DS:DATATYPE V';'
      V:ID|V','ID

     ES:ID'='V;
      E:NUMBER|ID

     CS:KEYWORD'('A')''{''}'
      A:ID AOP ID|ID AOP NUMBER|'}''}'

      R:RET NUMBER';'

%%
    int main()
   {
        yyin=fopen("client.c","r");
        yyparse();
    }   
    yyerror()
    {
            printf("\n ERROR AT LINE NO :%D",line);
    }
```

It's giving me following errors:

> yaac.y: warning: 11 nonterminals useless in grammar [-Wother]
>   yaac.y: warning: 18 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
>   yaac.y:7.8-12: fatal error: start symbol START does not derive any 
>   sentence
>    %start START

Comment: Your code is really hard to decipher. Please reformat your code according to the idioms normally used with Yacc, and try to create a _minimal_ example, not just a dump of your entire project.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the comments, it would be best to reformat the code in  proper yacc/bison format. In particular, grammar rules should start on the left of the page (column 1) and each rule should be terminated by a semicolon `;`. By missing the semicolons it is possible to confuse bison by running one rule into another.

Having done that, bison generates some clearer error message, which flag up that the non-terminal `E` is useless. You have not used `E` in any rule, which is probably an error in your grammar:

> yaac.y: warning: 1 nonterminal useless in grammar
>   yaac.y: warning: 2 rules useless in grammar
>   yaac.y:29.1: warning: nonterminal useless in grammar: E
>   yaac.y:29.3-8: warning: rule useless in grammar: E: NUMBER
>   yaac.y:29.10-11: warning: rule useless in grammar: E: ID

Just for completeness, this is how your grammar file looks after being tidied:

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    extern File *yyin;
    extern int line;
%}
%token DATATYPE NUMBER ID RET MAIN KEYWORD AOP HEADER STB ENB
%start START 
%%
START:H MAIN STB S R ENB
     ;

H:HEADER H|HEADER
    ;

S:DS S
       |ES S
       |CS S
       |;

DS:DATATYPE V';'
   ;

V:ID|V','ID
    ;

ES:ID'='V;
     ;

E:NUMBER|ID
    ;

CS:KEYWORD'('A')''{''}'
   ;

A:ID AOP ID|ID AOP NUMBER|'}''}'
    ;

R:RET NUMBER';'
    ;

%%
    int main()
   {
        yyin=fopen("client.c","r");
        yyparse();
    }   
    yyerror()
    {
            printf("\n ERROR AT LINE NO :%D",line);
    }
```